# :after pseudo selector on an image? CSS

Tags: html, css

Im trying to use the pseudo selector :after on an img tag to output an empty red div, only it isn't showing anything? am I using this correctly?...

```
img:after {background:red; content:'2'; height:100px; width:100px;}
```

**Jsfiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/MLReC/1/

Comment: You don't have the content: ''; property !

Comment: Even with that @Drip it doens't show anything? http://jsfiddle.net/MLReC/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:after` and other pseudo elements will not work with replaced elements such as `img`, `input` etc..

Comment: So I've just read, thanks for confirming this @Gaby

Answer (score 1):

you can put your image inside a div,p,etc.. tags and set :after selector on them.

HTML:

```
 <p>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100" />
</p>
```

CSS:

```
p:after{background:red; content:'2'; height:100px; width:100px;}
```